# Depenent JvmModelInferrer invoked twice?

Tags: gradle, xtext

**tldr;**
When I build a project with DSL-B (that depends on DSL-A) the generateXtext gradle task executes the JvmModelInferrer of DSL-A too often.

**Details**

Here is a simple example to reproduce the issue: [ex.xtext.twog](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog)

there are 2 xtext projects:

- [DSL A](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/tree/master/com.tmtron.ex.xtext.twog.a): grammar a which is independent
- [DSL B](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/tree/master/com.tmtron.ex.xtext.twog.a): grammar b, which references grammar a

and 2 demo projects, which use the xtext projects:

- [demo/demoA](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/tree/master/demo/demoA): (uses DSL a) with this simple [model](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/blob/master/demo/demoA/src/main/java/com/tmtron/modelA.dsla) `def DefStr java.lang.String`
- [demo/demoB](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/tree/master/demo/demoB): (uses DSL b) with this simple [model](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/blob/master/demo/demoB/src/main/java/modelB.dslb) `use UseStrCls DefStr`

I've added some debug-log messages to the [JvmModelInferrers](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/blob/master/com.tmtron.ex.xtext.twog.a/src/main/java/com/tmtron/ex/xtext/twog/jvmmodel/AJvmModelInferrer.xtend) to see what's going on.
The xtext generation in demoB calls the AJvmModelInferrer 3 times (see [build output](https://travis-ci.org/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/builds/340131079#L773)):

```
:demoB:generateXtext
AJvmModelInferrer: infer definition=DefStr isPreIndexingPhase=true
AJvmModelInferrer: infer definition=DefStr isPreIndexingPhase=false
BJvmModelInferrer: infer use=UseStrCls isPreIndexingPhase=true
BJvmModelInferrer: infer use=UseStrCls isPreIndexingPhase=false
AJvmModelInferrer: infer definition=DefStr isPreIndexingPhase=false
```

**Why is `AJvmModelInferrer` called again after `BJvmModelInferrer`?**

Note: I could not find good docs or examples on how to use multiple grammars, so it's well possible, that I am doing something wrong in my setup-here are the relevant parts:

- [BStandaloneSetup.createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration()](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/blob/master/com.tmtron.ex.xtext.twog.b/src/main/java/com/tmtron/ex/xtext/twog/BStandaloneSetup.xtend#L18) calls [AStandaloneSetup.doSetup()](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/blob/master/com.tmtron.ex.xtext.twog.a/src/main/java/com/tmtron/ex/xtext/twog/AStandaloneSetup.xtend#L12)
- [gradle.build](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/blob/master/demo/demoA/build.gradle#L8) of project `demoA` adds `src/main/java` as resource dir, so that the xtext-model A is in the jar file (and thus `demoB` can find it)

Comment: i would have expected multiple languages sections in the build.gradle

Comment: I don't need/want users in `DemoB` to create dsl-a model files (demoB should just be able to reference the model/s of demoA).
But anyway: I've created a new branch [BothLangsInDemoB](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/tree/BothLangsInDemoB): where I have added dsla to the [demoB build file](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/blob/BothLangsInDemoB/demo/demoB/build.gradle). But it still shows the same [behaviour](https://travis-ci.org/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/builds/340438824#L564)

Comment: sorry i have no idea about that. but why is it an issue?

Comment: maybe you can print a stacktrace who is calling it

Comment: The [stacktrace](https://travis-ci.org/tmtron/ex.xtext.twog/builds/340504899#L795) seems to indicate that it is called because of a proxy-resolution of a cross-ref. Do you think this is normal? e.g. because of the incremental nature of the compiler?

Comment: i wonder why the resource loaded before cannot be used